# How to create a select all button for a tkinter checkbox widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I copied the code from a previous question and tried to modify it to work with frames and grid manager but I can't seem to get it to work.  I think the problem may be in the create_cbuts function and the reference to frame1. Any help would be appreciated!

```
from tkinter import *           # Python interface to the Tk GUI toolkit
from tkinter import ttk         # Tk themed widget set
from tkinter import messagebox

def donothing():
   return
def create_cbuts():
    for index, item in enumerate(cbuts_text):
        cbuts.append(Checkbutton(frame1, text = item))
        cbuts[index].grid
def select_all():
    for i in cbuts:
        i.select()
def deselect_all():
    for i in cbuts:
        i.deselect()
def process_checkbox():
    if (check_an.get() == 1):
        print('Ancestry button checked')
    if (check_ft.get() == 1):
        print('FTDNA button checked')
    if (check_gm.get() == 1):
        print('GEDmatch button checked')
    if (check_mh.get() == 1):
        print('MyHeritage button checked')
    if (check_me.get() == 1):
        print('23&Me button checked')
root = Tk()

win2 = Toplevel(root)
win2.geometry('500x150')    # Width x Height
win2.resizable(0, 0)        # prevent window resizing
win2.title('Process DNA Match Files')
frame1 = Frame(win2)
frame2 = Frame(win2)
Label(frame1, text="Which files should be processed?").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
check_an = IntVar()
Checkbutton(frame1, text="Ancestry", variable=check_an).grid(row=1,column=0, sticky=W)
check_ft = IntVar()
Checkbutton(frame1, text="FTDNA", variable=check_ft).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
check_gm = IntVar()
Checkbutton(frame1, text="GEDmatch", variable=check_gm).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
check_mh = IntVar()
Checkbutton(frame1, text="MyHeritage", variable=check_mh).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
check_me = IntVar()
Checkbutton(frame1, text="23 and Me", variable=check_me).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
frame1.pack()
select_button = ttk.Button(frame2, text='Select All', width=15, command=select_all)
select_button.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
select_button = ttk.Button(frame2, text='Deselect All', width=15, command=deselect_all)
select_button.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
cancel_button =ttk.Button(frame2, text='Cancel', width=15, command=win2.destroy)
cancel_button.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
ok_button =ttk.Button(frame2, text='OK', width=15, command=process_checkbox)
ok_button.pack(side = LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
frame2.pack()
cbuts_text = ['Ancestry','FTDNA','GEDmatch','MyHeritage', '23 and Me']
cbuts = []
create_cbuts()
root.mainloop()
'''''
```

Comment: You seem to be creating the checkbuttons twice. Once in `create_cbuts` and once in the code after creating the toplevels.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Bryan. You pointed me in the right direction.  I deleted the create_cbuts function and modified the select_all and deselect_all functions as follows.  Less elegant but it works!

```
def select_all():
   check_an.set(True)
   check_ft.set(True)
   check_gm.set(True)
   check_mh.set(True)
   check_me.set(True)

def deselect_all():
   check_an.set(False)
   check_ft.set(False)
   check_gm.set(False)
   check_mh.set(False)
   check_me.set(False)
```

Comment: You can store the variables in a list if you like the tidyness of iterating over a loop.